# Spacemacs layer where package order matters

Tags: package, spacemacs

I'm trying to make a 'speedbar' layer that uses projectile-speedbar. The problem is projectile-speedbar won't compile unless sr-speedbar has already been compiled. Since spacemakes compiles the packages in alphabetical order, it tries to compile projectile-speedbar first and I get an error.

I have a packages.el for my layer in .emacs.d/private/speedbar:

```
(defvar speedbar-packages '(sr-speedbar projectile-speedbar))

(defun speedbar/init-sr-speedbar ()
  (use-package sr-speedbar))

(defun speedbar/init-projectile-speedbar ()
  (use-package projectile-speedbar
    :config (spacemacs/set-leader-keys
              "ft" 'projectile-speedbar-toggle)))
```

Is it possible to set this layer up so the sr-speedbar dependency is compiled first?

Comment: Seems to me that `projectile-speedbar` does not declare its dependencies correctly.

Comment: Any workaround? I was looking in to post-init hooks but I'm still very new to emacs and spacemacs. I would even be OK with hacking projectile-speedbar but I don't really know what to change.

Comment: It does look like an incorrect dependency declaration at `projectile-speedbar`, I sent a patch that should fix it: https://github.com/anshulverma/projectile-speedbar/pull/7

Comment: This seems to be heading in the right direction. But now I get an error "Cannot open load file: no such file or directory, projectile". And I'm stuck again, because projectile is clearly in the list you modified.